# Where to find ldb admin tool for RocksDB?

Tags: rocksdb

I read about RocksDB admin tool "ldb" on 
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Administration-and-Data-Access-Tool

But I could only find the ldb repo for leveldb:
https://github.com/0x00A/ldb

After compiling ldb, I cannot run either command from the links provided.

```
$ ldb -i ./db
Corruption: VersionEdit: unknown tag
```

or

```
$ ldb --db=./db
In excecutable 'ldb':
Unrecognized flag/option '--db=./db'
```

Where can I get the correct ldb admin tool for RocksDB, so at least I can browse through my existing RocksDB?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ldb tool for RocksDB is part of the code base: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/main/tools

You can build it by following the instructions in `INSTALL.md` and running `make ldb`.

Comment: see https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/10072 ,    If you compile RocksDB using the 'make static_lib' command, attempting to use 'make ldb' afterwards will result in compilation errors. The recommended approach is to directly use 'make all' to compile RocksDB along with its associated tools (such as ldb).